# Deploy NestJs server/API in NameCheap cPanel

Tags: deployment, nestjs, cpanel, namecheap

I've done it before, and documented how, but it wont work, and I'm at my wits end. I cannot for the life of me deploy NestJs in NameCheap cPanel. And I know there are several other posts with small comments, but none of them are helpful.

I've regressed to creating a basic, bare bones nest project and trying to deploy it, but it wont work.

1. create new nestjs project with `nest new basic-nest` with only the basic/root get endpoint that returns 'Hello World' from hitting the root endpoint(localhost:3000)

[image: NestJs Basic starter controller with Hello World]

2. The only thing I have changed is in main.ts changing
   await app.listen(3000) to await app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);

I thought somewhere that perhaps another api is running on port 3000 thus why not working, so I added the possibility of environment variable...

[image: updated env variable]

Also tried enableCors for all because why not

[! global enable CORS implemented](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Vxqx.png)][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Vxqx.png)

3. `nest build`
4. In cPanel, Setup Node.js App, configure as shown below, once created, stop the app to add package and dist files.

[image]

5. Now since creating the 'nest-basic' node application, going to the file manager, within the root home folder, the new folder 'nest-basic' was created. Within this folder I upload my package.json and create a dist folder, where i upload the dist files from 'nest build' from step 3.
6. Go back to cPanel -> Setup Node.js app -> edit 'nest-basic' app -> Run NPM Install(successful) -> Start App

7.Open the application url and nothing, everytime failure...

[image]

I'm not sure whats going wrong, Typescript compiled to JavaScript in the build, so its a NodeJs app, the build is executed through main.js in dist, and the package is installed in Namecheap NodeJS application setup, where I think the only dependency at this basic level that matters in production is @nestjs/core.

An alternate port is provided in environment variables but not necessary and CORS are enabled...
One thing that I had previously added in another project was a.npmrc file which only included the text "scripts-prepend-node-path=true", however, adding it next to package.json in the file manager and/or building the app with the file included, same result, failure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I slept on it, after a week of brute force attempts, I slept on it...

The fix was to include the prefix in the root get request

[image]

Or really you should instead update main.ts with setGlobalPrefix as shown below instead of including the '/nest-basic' in all of the routes as shown above

[image]

Also, the .npmrc file in this basic setup was unnecessary, I believe it had something to do with assisting the connection to MongoDB in Nest in the past project where it was required.

Leaving this post as its a more thorough walkthrough than other cPanel NestJs posts...and I'm sure I'll go through this again in x months after not doing it for while